# Splitting a file using perl

Tags: perl, split, csv-simple

I have a csv file and like to split the file into smaller files based on column matching in the file using perl. I am working on Linux Rhel6.

example:

```
fruit1, fruit2,pricerate,quantity
orange, apple, 3,9
apple,lemon,8,1
orange, apple,3,8
pineapple,papaya,9,19
orange,apple,3,7
pineapple,papaya,9,10
```

Output is something like:

file1:

```
fruit1,fruit2,pricerate,quantity
orange,apple, 3,9
orange,apple,3,8
orange,apple,3,7
```

file2:

```
fruit1,fruit2,pricerate,quantity
pineapple,papaya,9,19
pineapple,papaya,9,10
```

the unmatched ones goes into a seperate file. Say file3.

Comment: Just a question, Why do you think this question is related to Linux/Unix?

Comment: Also, where would `apple,lemon` go?

Comment: Apologies Saul - I should have mentioned earlier ..I am trying this in Linux rhel6.

Comment: hi choroba -  all the unmatched ones in a separate file

Comment: @namai No problem, please feel free to go back to your question editing it. Include all that information along the information you think is relevant for people that see it so, it would be easier for them to help you out with your problem (the more details related to your problem the better). Failure to do this will make the people that want to help frustrated and not willing to help. Take this as a suggestion from my part.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways in which you can solve this is:

- Open the input file
- Store the first line of the input file (the header)
- For every line in the input file after the header:

  - Read the first two columns
  - If we haven't opened an output file for the fields you want to match on yet, open a new output file and store its file handle in a hash. Write the header line to the new output file too.
  - Fetch the handle of the output file in which we should store this line from the file handle hash. Write the line to that file.

Here is some example code, which will match on the first two fields:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %filehandles=();
my $filenum=1;

open INPUT, "fruit.csv" 
    or die "Cannot open input file.";

my $header = <INPUT>;

while ( <INPUT> )
{   # Remove spaces from input 
    $_ =~ s/ //g;

    my @fields = split ',', $_;

    if ( ! $filehandles{$fields[0]}{$fields[1]} )
    {   open $filehandles{$fields[0]}{$fields[1]} , ">file$filenum"
            or die "Cannot open output file file$filenum.";
        print {$filehandles{$fields[0]}{$fields[1]}} $header;
        $filenum++;
    }
    print {$filehandles{$fields[0]}{$fields[1]}} $_;
}
```